# Apollo Server, typing an array of differently shaped objects

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am building a GraphQL layer on top of an existing REST api. In the schema, I have a key, "steps" that returns an array of differently shaped objects, of which one is an array of objects, like this

```
 "steps": [
       {
        "created_at": "a string",
        "created_by": "a string",
        "event_name": "a string",
        "reason": "failed",
      
      },
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "condition": false,
            "data": {
              "address": "foo",
              "address_city": "bar",
              "address_state": "baz",
            
            },
        
          }
        ],
```

I am able to get the first object returning, but am struggling with how to type this in order to access the components array, which is coming back as null in the graphQL playground. In my typeDefs, I am typing like this

```
  type Steps {
    event_name: String
    reason: String
    created_at: String
    created_by: String
    step_date: String
    step_name: String
    components: [Components]
  }
```

I understand WHY it's failing, as components is nested one extra level in it's own object, but I'm not sure what the fix is, since I can't just use a nested object in the type declaration and the individual objects in the steps array don't have keys.

Reading around the GraphQL docs, I can't see anything that explains how to type this sort of structure?

Comment: just adapt data to structure (before return in resolver), not structure to [strange] data shape?

Comment: can you elaborate @xadm - I'm not sure I follow...

Comment: ... show resolver